# Retrieve substitution value in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have some issues with my Apache rewrite rule and PHP.

Here is my rule:

```
RewriteRule /inscription /some/path/script.php [L]
```

Before rewrite I used `PHP_SELF` that gave me `/some/path/script.php` but now since rewrite, I got `inscription`.

How can I keep `PHP_SELF` as its original value? I need it to make some check on URL.

I thought to `REQUEST_URI` but it also give me `inscription`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get script path then you have to use `SCRIPT_NAME`

This will be more reliable than using others vars, a `var_dump($_SERVER);` will give you an overview of the paths in the `$_SERVER` array

To know more about it you should check php documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php